# Playing mp3 files over http in IOS

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, audio, mp3

Forgive me if this is already answered, believe me I've seen too many answers but can't find the one I can get to match exactly what I need.
I have a bunch of mp3 files on my web server.
I want to have an IOS application that connects to my server and streams the mp3 files. I do not need live streaming, I do not want to download the file and play it locally. 
I created a m3u file and I can point to it from my browser and it plays the files but when I used Apple's MovePlayer sample code it fails playing the file!

Any help as usual is appreciated.

Answer (score 6):

I personally don't know how to set up `MPMoviePlayer` to play .m3u files, however if you can accomplish the same task with an mp3, that can easily be done using `AVAudioFoundation`.

```
-(IBAction)playStreamMP3:(id)sender
{
    NSData *fetchedData = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://mysite.com/mysounds.mp3"]];
    if (data)
    {
        [data stop]; //data is an iVar holding any existing playing music
        data = nil;
    }
    data = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithData:fetchedData error:nil];
    data.delegate = self;
    [data play];
}
```

Comment: Simple and exactly what I needed! Is it safe to assume this uses http buffering? and the application that uses this won't be rejected by apple?

Comment: I believe that to be a safe assumption, and they shouldn't give you any trouble with this!

Comment: Just read this: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa1634/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40008185 It seems apple does not approve using AVAudioPlayer for http streaming, it's only recommended for local file play back. I keep looking.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think Apple's `MPMoviePlayerController` handle .m3u file format, but it's not a complicated format, you can always parse the playlist and feed actual mp3 url to it.

Comment: And how that's done? I don't want to download mp3 files. I want to stream the file. I can go to mp3 directly, I just thought m3u8 is the way to go!